# probability of a standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I haven't been able to make the sense of the following expression and use the table for standard normal distribution.

z<sub>.10</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the standard normal is symmetric about $0$, and by definition $\Pr(Z\le z_{0.1})=0.10$, it follows that $z_{0.1}$ must be *negative*.

Note also that by symmetry, for any $a$ we have $\Pr(Z\le -a)=\Pr(Z\ge a)$.

For what $a$ do we have $\Pr(Z\ge a)=0.10$? The right tail must have area $0.10$, so we must have $\Pr(Z\le a)=0.90$.

Now I expect you can use your table. Look in the body of the table until you see a number close to $0.9$. You should get something like $1.28$.

So $a\approx 1.28$, and therefore $-a$, our answer, is $\approx -1.28$.

Comment: but the answer is 1.28

Comment: There are two standard meanings is $z_{0.1}$. The more common one is the one that I used. Less common, but used occasionally, and perhaps by your text, is that $z_{0.1}$ is the place such that $\Pr(Z\gt z_{0.1})=0.1$.